# Processing error: expecting "class", found 'Set' in implemented interface method

Tags: java, processing

I have the following Entity-Component-System interface to represent a System (in `ECSSystem.java`):

```
interface ECSSystem extends Consumer<Set<Entity>> {
  public void accept(Set<Entity> entities);
  public Set<Class<? extends Component>> required();
}
```

where `Component` is an empty interface and `Entity` is a class.

I am then implementing the interface with the following code (in `PlayerInputSystem.pde`):

```
class PlayerInputSystem implements System {
  public void accept(Set<Entity> entities) {
    // implementation here
  }

  public Set<Class<? extends Component>> required() {
    final Set<Class<? extends Component>> reqs = new HashSet<>();
    // implementation here
    return reqs;
  }
}
```

For the line `final Set<Class<? extends Component>> reqs = new HashSet<>();` in `PlayerInputSystem.pde`, I get the following error:

```
expecting "class", found 'Set'
```

Is this just Processing (3.2.3) not understanding, or overriding the `Class` object? How can I fix it, or do I need to work around this?

EDIT: here is a minimum viable test example that fails with the same error:

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

void setup() {

}

void draw() {

}

interface Component {

}

class Entity {

}

interface ECSSystem extends Consumer<Set<Entity>> {
  public void accept(Set<Entity> entities);
  public Set<Class<? extends Component>> required();
}

class PlayerInputSystem implements ECSSystem {
  public void accept(Set<Entity> entities) {

  }

  public Set<Class<? extends Component>> required() {
    final Set<Class<? extends Component>> reqs = new HashSet<>(); // error here
    return reqs;
  }
}
```

Removing the `final` keyword where the error is reported then gives a new error:

```
unexpected token: ?
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the name `System` for your interface? You are going to have to do without some very common methods, such as `System.out.println` (unless you write `java.lang.System.out.println`).

Comment: @Eran Didn't think of that, yeah that's definitely something to change, thanks.

Comment: You can use Processing in eclipse and use a JDK that supports Processing and the diamond operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to post a [mcve] instead of a disconnected snippet. The code you posted contains a bunch of errors because you haven't included all of the classes we need. But instead of simply adding those classes, try to narrow your problem down to as few lines as possible. And like Eran said, you should really stay away from class names that are already being used.

Here is my attempt at getting around the classes you haven't provided, by just using `Object` instead. This compiles fine:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.awt.Component;

void draw(){

}

public interface System{
  public void accept(Set<Object> entities);
  public Set<Class<? extends Component>> required();
}

class PlayerInputSystem implements System {
  public void accept(Set<Object> entities) {
    // implementation here
  }

  public Set<Class<? extends Component>> required() {
    final Set<Class<? extends Component>> reqs = new HashSet<>();
    // implementation here
    return reqs;
  }
}
```

**Edit:** The real issue you have is that Processing doesn't support the diamond operator, which is what you're trying to use on this line:

```
final Set<Class<? extends Component>> reqs = new HashSet<>();
```

This is a known issue [here](https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/3054).

Comment: I've edited my question, which still fails with the same error message.

Comment: @BillyBrown See the edit at the bottom of my answer.